# Error in grub loader

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

As soon as i switch on my laptop i get grub loader [grub loader image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhlIs.jpg)

Then i type exit then i get booting option like the following image[booting option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i1ES.jpg)

If i select windows it loads properly but if i select Ubuntu then again it loads to grub loader[grub loader image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9zl7.jpg)

Its kind of endless loop nothing happens. Please can someone help i cant loose Ubuntu I have important files in it.

Comment: can you give the full image of second one? can you boot into kali?

Comment: No sir i tried to install kali linux long time back it had some error so i removed it and use it in virtual box. Just label of kali linux is left

Comment: I have edited the question with full image can you please check sir

Comment: ok can you boot into kali linux as in second picture?

Comment: No sir as i said its just a label nothing else i uninstalled it i just don't know how to remove that label of kali Linux option it wont start. As i enter it boot file not found message is displayed. Ubuntu is the problem sir not starting

Comment: If you have a liveCD of ubuntu then you can reinstall ubuntu if you have /home on different partition

Comment: I have sir but all my files in the previous Ubuntu will be lost na sir

Comment: how many partitions did you make?